# Warning: ob_start() [ref.outcontrol]: output handler 'ob_gzhandler' conflicts with zlib output compression'

Tags: php, apache, gzip, zlib

i am using the Gzip commpressionand Zlib commpression to speed up my website

I have used below code

`ob_start("ob_gzhandler");` 
in common file that are include on all pages and

```
lib.output_compression = On
```

But after this i get the error like

```
"Warning: ob_start() [ref.outcontrol]: output handler 'ob_gzhandler' conflicts with 'zlib output compression' in E:\xampp\htdocs\projects\trunk\index.php on line 2"
```

Can any one suggest me what's wrong in it?

Comment: Hi,After searching on google i came to know Gzip and Zlib both can not work together. You to use any one from above .So what i did  - lib.output_compression = Off
So anyone know how to use both compression to webiste?

Answer (score 7):

You should check if the zlib library loaded then clean the turn off output buffering by doing `ob_end_clean()`

You can add this line in the top of your file :
`<?php if (extension_loaded('zlib')){ ob_end_clean(); ob_start('ob_gzhandler');} ?>`

Answer (score 5):

Search line below in your php.ini file:

zlib.output_compression = On

change for:

zlib.output_compression = Off

Comment: wouldn't that be bad for your internet traffic? It would stop compressing the output and using more bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini, search 'zlib' and toggle to On

Answer (score 0):

**Recommendation : Dont use PHP Zlib compression, Turn it OFF**

**but try to Turn on Output Buffering**

Which helps Processed HTML are Started to Buffer immediately without waiting.. Which helps to speed up some mili secs.

Dont use too much PHP echo for normal HTML codes.

**Use**

- Webserver Gzip compressions
- Minify the HTML outputs
- Use Opcache and Static cache generators to Speedup your website 100% Gain.

Answer (score -1):

It's the same. You only need to do one of them, not both.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and your answer was very helpful.

Search line below in your php.ini file:

zlib.output_compression = On

change for:

zlib.output_compression = Off

However I could not figure out where to locate the php.ini file or the zlib.
I took a few days off and I looked over the above from a new perspective. My Hosting provider is "Hostinger"  http://api.hostinger.in/redir/21246281 they use the New Control Panel and you will access PHP Configuration here:
ps for cpanel users I will give an update if needed.

Here is an example of a php configure page on the Hostinger panel:

---

PHP Configuration

---

> PHP version

PHP 5.2
 PHP 5.3
 PHP 5.4
 PHP 5.5
 PHP 5.6
 PHP 7.0
Choose which PHP version you would like enabled for your account.

> **Zlib Compression**

**Enabled**
**Disabled**

Whether to transparently compress pages. If this option is set to "On" in php.ini, pages are compressed if the browser sends an "Accept-Encoding: gzip" or "deflate" header. "Content-Encoding: gzip" (respectively "deflate") and "Vary: Accept-Encoding" headers are added to the output. In runtime, it can be set only before sending any output.

> Display Errors

`Enabled` /  `Disabled` This determines whether errors should be printed to the screen as part of the output or if they should be hidden from the user.
Max Input Vars

Here is an example of the php configure admin panel page just make the change. Hope this was helpuful to someone.
goodloktimes@gmail.com